# Offheap leak after compiling with java 11

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory, java-11

After upgrading our Spring web app maven build to Java 11 we see a constant increase in memory consumption from the java process.

Works fine: Build with Java 8 JDK + run on server with Java 11

Has leak: Build with Java 11 + run on server with Java 11

The leak is not visible in a heap dump or even Native Memory Tracking, the process keeps increasing until physical memory + swap is full and the process is killed by the system. What kind of issue could even be causing this kind of problem?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but you have checked that it is not the Metaspace that is growing indefinitely and finally caused the JVM to be killed by the system? The Metaspace is holding the loaded classes and it is not part of the Heap.

Comment: @tquadrat Yea we have New Relic monitoring those stats and we see no outliers.

Comment: Have you tried it without the Monitoring thing, if you can get rid of that stuff easily?

Comment: @tquadrat Yea we read that java agents usage cant be tracked easily so we removed that startup flag but with no change.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information regarding the increasing size of the memory consumption? Any relevant reports from JVM tracking utilities? It seems like guessing in the dark without any additional information........

Comment: @RannLifshitz sorry but we have yet to find any information on this memory, all we see is increasing process and swap but none of the java tools report on this memory use.

Comment: @Jeppz Have you tried contacting anyone from Oracle regarding this issue? Via emails/forums/etc... ? They would probably have a better idea of where to look for potential build related memory leaks....

Comment: @Jeppz Was this solved? We are also facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Abhishek Sorry, no longer working there but it wasn't when I left.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 11 the ForkJoinPool class has a slightly different behaviour.

The default elapsed time since last use before a thread is terminated is 60 seconds. In Java 8 this was undocumented but actually hardcoded with 2 seconds. In case of oversized pools, the Java 8 implementation  terminates idle threads two seconds after the pool was  created. But the Java 9/11 version of the class keeps them alive for minutes.

Compare the number and lifetime of threads. Since unused threads may not be terminated early anymore when your application is started or ForkJoinPools objects are created the extended lifetime of threads could easily lead to a memory issue.

See the following question for a similar problem: 
[ForkJoinPool performance Java 8 vs 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084915/forkjoinpool-performance-java-8-vs-11)

In Java 9 a [new constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory,java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler,boolean,int,int,int,java.util.function.Predicate,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) was introduced to configure the value. To get the same behavior as with Java 8 compilation, you have to set *keepAliveTime* explicitly to 2 seconds or reduce the size of your  ForkJoinPool objects before you compile to Java 9.

Comment: Why should that depend on whether the code was compiled with Java 8 or Java 11?

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that also the Java 8 build was executed on a server with Java 11 and not on Java 8. So the changed behavior in ForkJoinPool cannot explain why the Java 8 build works fine on Java 11.

Comment: The behavior of ForkJoinPool has changed, no matter what Java build was used.
Therefore I would still suggest to have a closer look on the number of threads. They could be an explanation for the strange memory leak. Maybe there are also other differences between the two builds (e.g. due to multi-release JARs in 3rd party libraries) and maybe the combination makes the difference.

Comment: Hmm interesting point but our New Relic stats do not show an increased amount of threads since before the upgrade and we arent using ForkJoinPool (but I guess a dependency might).

Answer (score 1):

After digging a bit into Java's compiler code I found an interesting change, introduced in Java 9 which I wasn't aware of yet. This change CAN cause different behaviour depending on your compilation target:

While its widely known that most optimization are done by the JIT compiler instead of javac, the later still does some code optimizations. Before Java 9, one of these optimizations was the translation of String concatenations into StringBuilder::append chains. Starting with Java 9, javac makes use of *invokedynamic* calls to the newly introduced *java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory* class instead of translating to StringBuilder:append calls. So when you compile to Java 8, javac will produce optimized byte code, while when you compile to Java 9 optimization is delegated to the mentioned built-in class at runtime.

The corresponding [JEP 280](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8085796) provides some more details about this change. One success metric of the JEP 280 was that *String* concatenation performance must not regress. But  [JDK-8221760](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8221760) already reports a potential performance regression. According to the bug entry, code with string concatenation compiled to Java 8 seems to perform bettern on Java 11u than the same code compiled to Java 9 or 11. The bug entry is still unresolved, so maybe performance is not the only regression here.

Comment: But how does that cause a memory leak? Especially an off-heap memory leak? Unless StringConcatFactory leaks memory off heap