# How to get rid of the stray threads after calling parallelStream()

Tags: java, java-stream

There are some leftover ForkJoinPool worker threads after calling parallelStream(). They probably don't do any harm but I'm wondering whether there is a way to get rid of them technically.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public void test() {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Alex", "Bob", "Cathy", "David");
        
        printThreads();
        names.parallelStream().forEach(name -> {
            if (name.length() < 5) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Short name = %s", name));
            }
        });
        printThreads();
    }
    
    public void printThreads() {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        Thread[] listThreads = new Thread[thread.getThreadGroup().activeCount()];
        thread.getThreadGroup().enumerate(listThreads);
        System.out.println(String.format("List of threads: %s", Arrays.asList(listThreads)));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().test();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
List of threads: [Thread[main,5,main]]
Short name = Bob
Short name = Alex
List of threads: [Thread[main,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main]]
```

Onlinegdb link: https://onlinegdb.com/c2F_Tc1ko

Comment: There isn't a way.  You *could* shutdown the common forkjoinpool ... but that is a one way street.

Comment: And yes ... they don't do any harm.

Comment: @StephenC actually, no: [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#shutdown()): “*Invocation has no effect on execution state if this is the commonPool()*”. The simplest way to get rid of the worker threads, is to wait a few minutes. But there’s no advantage in doing so…

Comment: @holger, I waited 10 minutes and it doesn't seem to help. Am I doing it the wrong way (https://onlinegdb.com/QAj11GgGV)?

Comment: It’s the purpose of a thread pool to reuse threads and hence, keep them alive for some time to be able to pick up new tasks. The exact policy is an implementation detail and may change between Java versions. It seems, you tested it in an environment which keeps at least one thread alive indefinitely. See also [ForkJoinPool performance Java 8 vs 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54084915/2711488)